# Production build for react native for IIS Server

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a demo react native app in my development machine.Now i would like deploy this to a production server there is a script for react to do this but there no documents on bundling the native app on production server.

Any Help is highly appreciated.....

**[Update1]:** The idea is to run a react native app using web screens from server.In detail once the user install the apk and open the app the home screen should be served from the server.I google for hours and could not find any useful resource i tried to bundle the app (web components plus native) but it was not successful. Hope i explained my problem.

This [link](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/so-you-want-to-dynamically-update-your-react-native-app-d1d88bf11ede) by Clay Allsop explains the situation more briefly.

Comment: maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem, but react native isn't normally something you run on a server.....

Comment: Tag description: "React Native lets you build **mobile apps**"... Where did you find a reference that an external web server is necessary?

Comment: yes it is for mobile but my idea was to update the ui screen dynamically from the server so i was thinking of bundling app and ship it to a production server.Is this possible.In   [these](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/blob/master/docs/guides/getting-started.md)  links you can see we can use react native for web so then it should be possible to bundle a production build and deploy in server.